# How to display randomly scattered textviews (like in Apple presentation feature lists)?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-layout, textview

Say you've a list of Strings. The number of Strings varies. Is there a way to randomly display these strings like in an Apple presentation when they show a bunch of features in a slide. See link for an example.

http://www.technobuffalo.com/2011/06/10/iphone-5-feature-hinted-at-in-ios-5-wwdc-presentation/

So, text is randomly scattered but never overlaps. Spacing is pretty even. Some text is dim, some is bolder, big, small, etc. I couldn't find the 'name' of this effect (or these multiple combined effects) if there even is one?

I assume they do it manually in a slide of course, but I was wondering if there was a known way of doing this programmatically.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: have you tried doing it by `Random` ?

Comment: I'm thinking if there is a standard way to automate this for a variable number of items, it probably exists as a library, I just don't know if there is a term for that effect